# One to One XSLT map with namespace manipulations

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://root" xmlns:nm="http://notroot">
  <nm:MSH>
    <content>bla</content>
  </nm:MSH>
  <ns0:Second>
    <ns0:item>aaa</ns0:item>
  </ns0:Second>
  <ns0:Third>
    <ns0:itemb>vv</ns0:itemb>
  </ns0:Third>
</ns0:Root>
```

That is my expected result:

```
<Root xmlns="http://root" xmlns:nm="http://notroot">
  <nm:MSH>
    <content>bla</content>
  </nm:MSH>
  <Second>
    <item>aaa</item>
  </Second>
  <Third>
    <itemb>vv</itemb>
  </Third>
</Root>
```

I need to write an xslt 1.0 that perform that map.

I really doesn't have a clue how to do it, thus it seems pretty simple.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the elements from `xmlns:ns0="http://root"` namespace to default namespace.
Use:

```
    <xsl:template match="ns0:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

To make `http://root` the default namespace add `xmlns="http://root"`to the stylesheet declaration.

Therefore you may try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:ns0="http://root" 
    xmlns="http://root" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0" >
    <!-- Identity transform (e.g.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match root element and fore notroot namespace to this -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Root xmlns:nm="http://notroot">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </Root> 
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="content">
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </content>
    </xsl:template>
     <!-- move attributes with prefix ns0 to default namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="@ns0:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="newns:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

     <!-- move elements with prefix ns0 to default namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="ns0:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1.  And finally, add `exclude-result-prefixes="ns0"` to get rid of the redundant `xmlns:ns0` declaration on the output `Root` element.

Comment: Thanks! It works! can you please explain what each template is doing ?

Comment: @ohadinho: I add some comments.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your input and output is that the `content` element inside `nm:MSH` has moved from being in no namespace to being in the `http://root` namespace.  This can be handled by an identity transformation with tweaks:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
      xmlns:ns0="http://root">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <ns0:content><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></ns0:content>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```